# Is it okay not to close HTML tags like <img> with />?

Tags: html, xhtml

I always learned to close HTML tags like `img`, `meta` etc. like this:

```
<img src="..." />
<meta charset="..." />
<hr />
<br />
<input type="..." />
```

But I've seen numerous sites that don't put the `/>` at the end. They simply put `>` at the end. Which results in:

```
<img src="...">
<meta charset="...">
<hr>
<br>
<input type="...">
```

But to me that doesn't seem right... How can a browser know if a tag still needs to be closed somewhere when you do it like that? That's also how I learned it years ago.

But even [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) is closing `input` tags without `/>` at the end.

Is this really valid HTML? And is it now a preferred way of doing it?

Comment: see http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/html-vs-xhtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<foo />` is XML syntax. It is meaningful only in XML (including XHTML).

However, let us deal with HTML.

> How can a browser know if a tag still needs to be closed somewhere when you do it like that?

Some elements have required end tags. These must have an explicit `</foo>`

Some elements cannot have any child nodes and must not have an explicit `</foo>`. For example `<img>`.

Some elements have optional end tags (such as `<p>`). Browsers will close these elements when either they encounter an explicit end tag (`</p>`) they they encounter the start tag for an element that is not allowed as a child node inside that element (such as a `<div>` inside a `<p>` or a `<li>` inside another `<li>`).

Browsers know which elements have required, optional or forbidden end tags because they are programmed to recognise HTML.

HTML 5 allows the `/>` syntax  on elements either forbidden end tags, but that is just syntactic sugar for people addicted to XML.

Comment: Regarding “Some elements cannot have any child nodes and must not have an explicit `</foo>`”: such explicit end tags *are* allowed. XML, and hence XHTML, allows e.g. `<img ...></img>` as an altenative to `<img .../>`. Such notation is not recommended according to XHTML 1.0 for compatibility reasons (which is really too cautious, since in tagsoup parsing, `</img>` is just ignored).

Comment: @Jukka: Explicit end tags were never allowed for void elements in HTML. They're only legal in XML (and XHTML).

Answer (score 0):

This is valid in HTML5, but not in XHTML. I personally prefer using this, just because is saves some bytes.